# How to switch an unempty time series data type from FLOAT to DOUBLE in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

If a time series was created before in Apache IoTDB, and the data type was FLOAT. Also, part of the data has already been inserted in the time series. Now I want to change the data type of time series to DOUBLE. I wonder if IoTDB can change the data type of time series? If it can, how can I do this?

I stop the server to prevent any further data insertion or query execution. Then, I use the ALTER statement to modify the data type of the time series.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another time series in Apache IoTDB with `DOUBLE` datatype, and use `select into` to write the original data into this time series.